# Very Specific Bug - Tic Tac Toe Tester

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, debugging

I provided **WAY** too much info last time, so I'll reduce it.

I have a tic-tac-toe program I'm writing, but before I introduce the **AI**, I need to fix this bug.

#### Use Case:

- **4x4 grid**
- Selecting 3 on the right col, and either "index 2" or "index 3" for the bottom row.

Doing this produces a false win. I have tested this with **EVERY** other use case, and this is the only bug I've found so far. (images provided below):

[image]
[image]

**It has to do with my checking system. I've provided the `array` it is testing for the `bug`, as well as the `code to find a win`.**

```
var b = [ ["", "", "", "X"],
          ["", "", "", "X"],
          ["", "", "", "X"],
          ["", "", "X", ""] ]

function testWin() {
    var len=b.length, r=0, c=0, dr=0, dl=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        c=0;
        for(var j=0;j<len;j++){
            (b[j][i]==="X") ? c++ : c=0;
            (b[i][j]==="X") ? r++ : r=0;
            if(b[i][j]==="X" && i<len-win+1){ 
                dr=0; dl=0;
                for(var z=0;z<win;z++){ 
                    (b[i+z][j+z]==="X") ? dr++ : dr=0;
                    (b[i+z][j-z]==="X") ? dl++ : dl=0;
                }
            }
            if(c===win || r===win || dr===win || dl===win){ 
                         alert("YOU WIN!"); return true;
            }
         } 
         r=0;
    }
}
```

(I know, lots of ternary operators... hopefully it makes sense still. I built it from scratch, so I can elaborate if anybody needs me to.)

- Live Site (with comp): http://sinsysonline.com/tictactoe_test.html
- Full Fiddle (with comp): http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/9kzeq/
- Reduced Fiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/LNT6j/1/

Comment: what is the value of `win`?

Comment: You know that it fails for a check in the n-1 column for the last row, for any n (2,3 as well as 4)?

Comment: Can you explain this algorithm in words?   I've stared at it for a little while, and I can't.

Comment: @GreenAsJade that is for his diagnols and I am pretty sure thats where its messing up

Comment: This version of the question has the right amount of information.  Though - it would have been even better if the code you posted was formatted correctly ;)

Comment: Answer is dead and solved. So, I ask, @GreenAsJade , what was formatted **INCORRECTLY**? The headings I added? :-) Sorry to throw emphasis on things. Do you have a link I could read up on proper formatting? Still kind of new here... love to know the ropes :-)

Comment: The way he's doing diagonals is completely unnecessary. You just need to check `b[i][len - i - 1]` and `b[i][i]` each time through the outer loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: The headings you used were not to someone's taste - I guess they were distracting.   Most importantly though, your code was hard to read because it was laid out inconsistently.   You randomly put code on the same lines as open and close braces, and (most importantly) the body of clauses and their closing braces were "all over the place" :)      The latter was largely (soley?) due to pasting in code that contained tabs, which did not resolve properly here.   The former is something I would suggest you do less of - the savings in vertical space are more than offset by the loss of clarity.

Comment: Thank you :-) I tested the crap out of it, tried to golf my code a tad, and ended up stuck without a backup. I appreciate your answer :-). As a forum moderator though, was this considered a legitimate question?

Comment: This is definitely a legitimate question.  If it wasn't you can be sure it would have been downvoted before you could blink :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the column counter `c` each time the loop moves to the next column.

```
function testWin() {
    var len=b.length, r=0, c=0, dr=0, dl=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        c=0;
        for(var j=0;j<len;j++){
            (b[j][i]==="X") ? c++ : c=0;
            (b[i][j]==="X") ? r++ : r=0;
            if(b[i][j]==="X" && i<len-win+1){ dr=0; dl=0;
                for(var z=0;z<win;z++){ 
                    (b[i+z][j+z]==="X") ? dr++ : dr=0;
                    (b[i+z][j-z]==="X") ? dl++ : dl=0;
                }
            }
            if(c===win || r===win || dr===win || dl===win){ alert("YOU WIN!"); return true;}
        } r=0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Here is a way to do it with only two loops:**

```
function testWin() {
    var len=b.length, r=0, c=0, dr=0, dl=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        r=0, c=0, dr=0, dl=0;
        for(var j=0;j<len;j++){
            (b[j][i]==="X") ? c++ : c=0;
            (b[i][j]==="X") ? r++ : r=0;
            if(i+j<len){ z = i+j;} else{z = i+j-len, dr=0, dl=0;}
            (b[j][z]==="X") ? dr++ : dr=0;
            (b[j][len-1-z]==="X") ? dl++ : dl=0;
            if(c===win || r===win || dr===win || dl===win){ alert("YOU WIN!"); return true;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **OH MY F*@&$(G GOD I LOVE YOU.**
Been hammering my head against this for weeks, and it's been so **SIMPLE**. I wish I could upvote more than once! How in the world did I not see this...? THANK YOU AGAIN!!!

Comment: There's also no need to check inside the inner loop. You were a little faster than me, but I cleaned it up some in my answer.

Comment: Just check once after you're done with the row. That's really the point of the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just had a fiasco trying to figure out diagonals without an `if statement`. Must have missed the precursor :-P

Comment: You can reward a particularly helpful answer with a bounty if you are keen.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work  "Can I award a bounty to an old answer".

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem I see is that you should be performing the row and column checks *after* each row is processed. I believe the following works:

```
var b = [["X", "", "", "X"],
         ["", "X", "X", "X"],
         ["", "X", "X", "X"],
         ["", "X", "X", ""]]
var win = 4;

function testWin() {
    var len = b.length;
    var dr = 0,
        dl = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var c = 0, 
            r = 0;
        dr += (b[i][len - i - 1] === "X") ? 1 : 0;
        dl += (b[i][i] === "X") ? 1 : 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            c += (b[j][i] === "X") ? 1 : 0;
            r += (b[i][j] === "X") ? 1 : 0;
        } 
        console.log(c, r, dl, dr);
        if (c === win || r === win || dr === win || dl === win) {
            alert("YOU WIN!"); 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Second, I don't mind ternarys, but you should write them like this:

```
c += (b[j][i] === "X") ? 1 : 0;
```

The way you're doing it obscures the point of the expression.

This version also drastically improves the diagonal check. You really just need to increment one value for each diagonal each time through the outer loop and check the totals once the outer loop is done. (I've included this check in the same expression as the one for rows and columns, because that's a little bit cleaner, but it's unnecessary.) You do not need another inner loop, in other words.

Comment: It throws a false what?

Comment: Wow, my mouse has been acting up (probably due to the ash from my cigarettes all day long). I must've double clicked it, cause I retested and it worked fine. *deleting prior comments*

Comment: Do you have any supported link where I can read up more? Looking at your code I fully understand it, but I want a deeper understanding. I'd appreciate any additional resources you could offer.

Comment: I just updated with a much improved diagonal check. Take a look. (Sorry, don't have any links. The important thing is just to read through it step-by-step, mapping out what each variable's value is at the end of each loop. Take a look at the `console` logging for some help.)

Comment: [Here is what I came up with](http://sinsysonline.com/cap3.JPG) I really think it was as simple as resetting the `c` value.

Comment: Resetting the column does indeed fix the problem. I would argue that my answer goes *beyond* fixing the problem :)

Comment: I would 100% agree, and the knowledge you have provided WILL be used in future projects, and I appreciate that (hence the upvote). Thank you. This project is literally a **down-time, make something interesting** kind of thing.

Comment: @lwburk This is a good solution, but will not work if the variable `win` is less than the length of `b`.

Comment: Good point. I'd probably go with a solution that parameterized the win length. In traditional tic-tac-toe, these are one and the same, but a more general solution *would* be better.

Comment: Well, tested both, and here is what I found. Maybe I have buggy code, [but your's doesn't necessarily work](http://sinsysonline.com/nowin.JPG) The problem is, I'm already giving players the option to play up to a **10x10** grid with different **winning values**... so I understand your opinion on `ternary operators` but so far I feel it's working fine.

Comment: @NicholasHazel - Yes, I didn't realize your game was different from traditional tic-tac-toe. That's what we were just talking about. In that case, you would need to check all diagonals. It's a good point.

Comment: Thank you :-) I could build tic-tac-toe in 10 mins. I wanted to expand, and give people the option to select **Nicolas Cage** as their player and play on a huge grid system, similar to the **Connect-4** game, but expanded further. The **AI** is going to be a pain... **And yes, your option worked and these posts are HEAVILY cached by Google, so somebody should learn from it :-) )**. No point in building `machine-learning` without working code first :-)

Comment: I now see what you were doing in your innermost loop. I solved a slightly different problem. My original answer (see edit history) still stands for the original problem, but I think I'll leave this alone as a counterpoint for the traditional tic-tac-toe situation. After all, lots more people will read this than just you.

Comment: I will note that there's still no reason to check the diagonals *inside* the row/column loops.

Comment: Only way I could make it work after hours (4) of testing. Care to continue in chat? I'd love a quick fix to make it faster...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46097/discussion-between-lwburk-and-nicholas-hazel)

Comment: Check out my answer. I just added a version using only two loops that will work with variable `win` lower than the width of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

## WORKING!

### Thank you all!

#### http://sinsysonline.com/tictactoe_test.html

It was as simple as adding:

```
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    c=0; // <----- THIS
    for(var j=0;j<len;j++){
```

### Time to build an AI :-)